# SharpArch.Core.PreconditionException

Tags: nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

I get this:

"A storage mechanism has already been configured for this application"

The thing is - I already have another s#arp archtecture web app successfuly running on the server - could this be the problem?

I have this:

private void InitializeNHibernateSession()
        {
            NHibernateSession.Init(
                webSessionStorage,
                new string[] { Server.MapPath("~/bin/Bla.Data.dll") },
                new AutoPersistenceModelGenerator().Generate(),
                Server.MapPath("~/NHibernate.config"));
        }

which should be ok.

Thanks!

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Try to run iisreset command

Answer (score 0):

i move my app from work to home regularly.  i get this error all the time when changing connection strings.  in my case i just need to recompile.  recompiling your app doesn't fix the problem?